# Three.JS object rendering in AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I'm currently trying to integrate Three.JS into an AngularJS directive. At the moment I'm really just looking for a proof-of-concept execution that I can use as boilerplate for a more complex directive later on.

At the moment I'm using the `link` function of the directive to setup the Three.JS scene and initiate the animation.

The scene renders fine, and the animation is being called fine, but the object I've added to the scene isn't rendering.

I've tried:

1. Adjusting the camera POV, position, aspect ratio
2. Increasing the size of the object
3. Adjusting the color of the object

I'm not sure if it's a matter of the object simply being out of view/invisible for some reason, or if the object is just not in the scene. 
Within the `render` function I did use `console.log` and confirmed that the object was being found in the `scene.traversal` function call, and its rotation was being adjusted as expected.

I've confirmed the same code renders and animates an object outside

Below is the directive in full, and [here is a link to it in JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/turebi/1/edit)

```
angular.module('nxGeometry', [])
  .directive('nxGeometry', function(){

    return {

      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        // Scene variables

        var camera, scene, geometry, renderer, material, object, container;


        // Element dimensions

        scope.width           = element[0].offsetWidth;
        scope.height          = element[0].offsetHeight;
        scope.objectColor     = '#ffaa44';
        scope.backgroundColor = '#333333';

        // Initialization function

        scope.init = function(){


          container = angular.element('<div>')[0];

          element[0].appendChild(container);

          camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, scope.width / scope.height, 1, 1000);

              camera.position.x = 5;
              camera.position.y = 0;
              camera.position.z = 0;


          scene    = new THREE.Scene();

          geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);

          material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "#ffffff"});

          object   = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

              object.position.x = 0;
              object.position.y = 0;
              object.position.z = 0;

              scene.add(object);

          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

              renderer.setSize(scope.width, scope.height);
              renderer.setClearColor(scope.backgroundColor);

          container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        }; // @end scope.init

        scope.render = function(){

          camera.lookAt(scene);

          // Traverse the scene, rotate the Mesh object(s)
          scene.traverse(function(element){

            if(element instanceof  THREE.Mesh){

              element.rotation.x += 0.0065;
              element.rotation.y += 0.0065;
            }

          renderer.render(scene, camera);

          });

        }; // @end scope.render


        scope.animate = function(){

          requestAnimationFrame(scope.animate);
          scope.render();

        };

        scope.init();
        scope.animate();

      }

    };

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your camera was not pointing on the object. Just increase z to 5 and your object will be visible.

`camera.lookAt(scene);` is not working because you have to add the position of the scene. Like this `camera.lookAt(scene.position);`.

Please find the updated code [here](http://jsbin.com/macabolemu/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

These things I've changed:

```
camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, scope.width / scope.height, 1, 1000);

camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 5;

....
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

Comment: `scene.position`! That's the missing piece, thank you. I'm not sure why it was working outside of angular without the `position` reference, but it's working now.